# Working with NSMutableArray in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` skippedArray of strings.

```
skipped Array = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"];
```

I want to assign the string at index 0 to an `UILabel`.

I tried `lblQuestion.text =  skippedArray[j] as! String`
but the app crashes at this line.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can create the array like this, skippedArray : [String] = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"];   In this case, no need to cast the value to String.

Comment: What is the crash? and why are you using NSMutableArray in swift? you should just use var arr = []

Comment: Can you please share crash report.

Comment: The crash states - "Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x10c6e71d8) to 'NSString' (0x1098ffc40)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define NSMutableArray like this:

```
let skippedArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"];
lblQuestion.text =  skippedArray.first
```

or you may also code like this:

```
let skippedArray : NSMutableArray =         ["string1","string2","string3","string4"];
lblQuestion.text =  skippedArray.firstObject as! String
```

There is another way to fetch object of NSMutableArray like this:

```
let skippedArray : NSMutableArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"];
 let j = 0;
lblQuestion.text =  skippedArray.object(at: j) as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable as Array or simply [String] or just let the definition define it as follows:

```
var skippedArray: Array<String> = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
```

or

```
var skippedArray: [String] = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
```

or

```
var skippedArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define Mutable Array properly, as mentioned before

```
var skippedArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
```

Second, define your index, your called this "j"

```
let j = 0
```

Third, set label text with your string, from string array

```
lblQuestion.text =  skippedArray[j]
```